# In RCL, how to embed file generated at build time?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, msbuild

I have a Razor Class Library project which I would like to compile into a single .dll with all static resources embedded.

Embedding can easily be done for resources from `wwwroot` - with the following lines in `.csproj`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>true</GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
      <EmbeddedResource Include="wwwroot\**" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded" Version="7.0.5" />
</ItemGroup>
```

However, in RCL we can also use the **scoped css** mechanism, i.e. files named "componentName.razor.css" spread throughout the project (they must be located alongside components). At **build**, those files are processed (by adding scoping to css selectors) and bundled into a single assemblyName.styles.css file, temporarily located under `obj\Release\net7.0\scopedcss\bundle\` (path parts can be different depending on build configuration and target framework). This file is later copied to wwwroot directory when **publishing** the library.

If I try to just embed the file from the location where it is going to exist, build fails - at the time embedding is performed the target file has not been generated yet:

```
<ItemGroup>
      <EmbeddedResource Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)\scopedcss\bundle\$(AssemblyName).styles.css">
            <LogicalName>wwwroot.$(AssemblyName).styles.css</LogicalName>
      </EmbeddedResource>
 </ItemGroup>
```

[image: error message - 'Could not find file']

Of course, I could just directly embed all the `.razor.css` files - but I would then loose the scoping mechanism (enforced by selector modifications that compiler makes while bundling), which is the entire point of using them.

My question is then: **how can I embed the** `assemblyName.styles.css` **file generated at build time into library's main .dll?**

My guess is that it could be achieved with MSBuild tasks, like in [Inject EmbeddedResource created by MSBuild Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50035598/inject-embeddedresource-created-by-msbuild-task), but I can't get it right.

Comment: Compilation of the assembly is done before the `assemblyName.styles.css` is generated. I don't know the [Razor SDK project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/sdk?view=aspnetcore-7.0) support. I expect there is a target that handles the `assemblyName.styles.css` generation and that it is executing after `Compile`. If you define a target that runs early (e.g. BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild") and that depends on the CSS generation target you can cause the CSS generation to be done before `Compile` - assuming that CSS generation doesn't need `Compile` to be done first.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. But where can I look for the RCL compilation definition - i.e. defined targets and their order? I've tried to browse the source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/razor), but all I can find are .csproj and .targets/.props files that seem to be relevant to the compilation of the SDK itself. Where can compilation of RCL libraries be defined? What kind of files should I look for?

Comment: The .csproj (C# project) file is an MSBuild file. When the project file starts with `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` or `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">` the `SDK` attribute is used to import a set of files. Running your project with `msbuild -preprocess` (or `dotnet msbuild -preprocess`) produces the aggregation of all the imports. (See [MSBuild command-line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2022).) Producing the 'preprocesed' file is a good starting place.

Comment: `Build`, `Clean`, and `Rebuild` are always defined targets. When you choose those commands from the IDE's Build menu, the IDE is running msbuild with `-target` set to the appropriate target. Find the `Build` target and see what it depends.

Comment: Another trick: use the `-targets` (with an 's') switch to report all the targets available in your .csproj file. You may be able to make some guesses about which to look at based on the names.

Comment: Thank you - proper use of `msbuild` CLI with `-preprocess` and `-targets` options proved extremly useful. As a side note, I was getting significantly better formatted output using command `dotnet msbuild` instead of just `msbuild`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to guidance by @Jonathan Dodds (see comments) I was able to embed the generated asseblyName.style.css file in the RCL .dll.

Bundled scoped css file I mentioned in the question turns out to be generated in the `BundleScopedCssFiles` target.

The solution is to add the following to the RCL .csproj file:

```
<Target Name="EmbedScopedCss" BeforeTargets="Build" DependsOnTargets="BundleScopedCssFiles">
      <ItemGroup>
            <EmbeddedResource Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)\scopedcss\bundle\$(AssemblyName).styles.css">
                 <LogicalName>wwwroot.$(AssemblyName).styles.css</LogicalName>
            </EmbeddedResource>
      </ItemGroup>
 </Target>
```

(The `LogicalName` property under `EmbeddedResource` is not required, but it makes embedded file named as if it existed in the `wwwroot` directory.)

I also had to add my target to project's `InitialTargets` (otherwise it was ignored):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor" InitialTargets="EmbedScopedCss" >
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained by Jonathan Dodds,Compilation of the assembly is done before the assemblyName.styles.css is generated.I haven't found any solution embed it into the dll of RCL,but you could try embed it into main project follow this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69366052/how-to-embed-the-scoped-css-bundle-file-generated-by-razor-class-library)

Comment: Thank you. Solution you pointed to is relevant and can be useful, but in my case embedding into the main project is not an option.